# Putting a list into a list at each new line

Tags: python, list, slice, bioinformatics, nested-lists

I am trying to create a new list (within a list) for each set of kmers

**For example** it should return:

```
[['ATT', 'TTT', 'TTG', 'TGG', 'GGC'], ['TGC', 'GCC', 'CCT', 'CTT', 'TTA'], ['CGG', 'GGT', 'GTA', 'TAT', 'ATC'], ['GAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAT', 'ATT']]
```

Instead of this:

```
['ATT', 'TTT', 'TTG', 'TGG', 'GGC', 'TGC', 'GCC', 'CCT', 'CTT', 'TTA', 'CGG', 'GGT', 'GTA', 'TAT', 'ATC', 'GAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAT', 'ATT']
```

My code

```
  # data = ['ATTTGGC', 'TGCCTTA', 'CGGTATC', 'GAAAATT']
    kmers = []
    def findKmersSet(k, stuff):
        i=0
        for line in data:
            for i in range(0,int(len(line)-k+1)):
                kmers.append(line[i:i+k])
    findKmersSet(3, data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then do create a list for each line:

```
kmers = []
def findKmersSet(k, stuff):
    for line in data:
        line_list = []
        for i in range(0,int(len(line)-k+1)):
            line_list.append(line[i:i+k])
        kmers.append(line_list)

findKmersSet(3, data)
```

Comment: Though this other answer is better of course, I just showed the most obvious way.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick - the point is to create a new list for each initial string and append it to the total results list:

```
data = ['ATTTGGC', 'TGCCTTA', 'CGGTATC', 'GAAAATT']

def findKmersSet(k, stuff):
    result = []
    for inner_list in stuff:
        iterators = [iter(inner_list[i:]) for i in xrange(k)]
        result.append([''.join(triple) for triple in zip(*iterators)])

    return result


findKmersSet(3, data)
# [['ATT', 'TTT', 'TTG', 'TGG', 'GGC'], ['TGC', 'GCC', 'CCT', 'CTT', TTA'], ['CGG', 'GGT', 'GTA', 'TAT', 'ATC'], ['GAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAT', 'ATT']]
```